# Discussion about tag: uninstall

Tags: discussion, tags

The [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) says:

> Questions about uninstalling software in Ubuntu, or uninstalling Ubuntu from a computer.

And [software-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-uninstall) says:

> for questions about uninstalling software on Ubuntu.

So, I think [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) is a general tag and its excerpt needs to be improved.

---

Something like [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) says:

> **DO NOT USE THIS TAG**. Use either [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) (for system installs) or [software-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation) (for installing software on a running system). Questions about installing Ubuntu, or installing programs from within Ubuntu.

So, users are recommended to use specific [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) or [software-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation) instead.

---

Similarly, [software-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-uninstall) is specific. So, either [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) should say :

> Questions about uninstallation. This is very general tag. If you have a tag that's more specific e.g. ([software-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-uninstall) for uninstalling software) please use that one.

(something like [updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/updates) says)

And/or There should be tag for uninstalling system like [system-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-uninstall) as well as [software-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-uninstall)

Comment: Yes to everything except the system-uninstall tag, which is a misnomer from my point of view and should only have a few questions. On second thought if users find questions with appropriate answers more easily through this tag, then this is a good thing.